# import html value in a php function

Tags: php, button

I have this code that fetches information in a file and shows the result. That all works as expected. What I'm not able to do is to export the button value in the function when it is pressed so the value of the pressed button will transfer to a variable in my php function. How can I do that?

Here the code:

```
<h2>Demmarage script torrent</h2> 
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input_value">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php
echo "<br>";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $findme = $_POST['input_value'];
    $findme1 = str_replace (" ", ".", $findme); 
    $savedarr = unserialize(file_get_contents('torrent.bin'));

    foreach ($savedarr as $val1){
        $mystring = $val1['title'];
        if((stripos($mystring, $findme) !== false) or (stripos($mystring, $findme1)  !==    false)) {
            echo "Show trouve: ";
            echo $mystring;
            ?>

            <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $val1['link']; ?>" name="editId">Telecharger</button>

            <?php
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['editId'])){
    //Here i want to import the value of the pressed button to do something
    echo "download start";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use  a hidden field, like

```
<input type="hidden" name="link" id="link" value="<?php echo $val1['link'] ?>" />
```

After the submit you will be able to get the value with

```
$_POST['link']
```

Also, this should be in a form,otherwise the submit will post EVERY field ...

like

```
foreach(...)
{?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="link" id="link" value="<?php echo $val1['link'] ?>" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
<?php}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the value twice by `<button>value1</button>` and by `<button value="value2">`... remember that the value of a submit button is always the text that shows up inside the button.

**You should do replace this:**

```
<button type="submit" value="<?php echo $val1['link']; ?>" name="editId">Telecharger</button>
```

**with this:**

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$val1['link']?>" name="editId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Telecharger" />
</form>
```